# Subclassing a Subclass of an NSManagedObject

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

i try to keep my NSManagedObject-Subclasses tidy and clean as they generated but i want to add certain functionallity.

My first idea was to subclass the subclass.

For example, my Account is generated and looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Account: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var displayName: String
    @NSManaged var host: String
    @NSManaged var port: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var schema: String
    @NSManaged var username: String
}
```

Than I subclassed it and add an class func to initialize a new one.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class AccountModel: Account {

    static var entityName = "Account"

    class func createAccount(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> AccountModel {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let account = AccountModel(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        return account
    }
}
```

My Unittest works fine for this part:

```
func testCreateAccount(){
    let account = AccountModel.createAccount(managedObjectContext!)
    dump(account)

    let accounts = AccountModel.getList(managedObjectContext!)
    XCTAssertEqual(accounts.count, 1, "There is no account created, yet")
}
```

But if a add a new function or a computed property to the AccountModel I've got a BAD_ACCESS error.

```
class AccountModel: Account {
    [...]
    func foo(){
        println("bar")
    }
}
```

And in my Test:

```
let account = AccountModel.createAccount(managedObjectContext!)
account.setValue("localhost", forKey: "host")
account.setValue(8080, forKey: "port")
account.setValue("https", forKey: "schema")    
account.foo()
```

*account* seams to be an instance from Account, not from AccountModel.

Can you help me to solve this problem of seperating the generated Class from the model class?

Thanks a lot. 
ps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably Swift compiler bug. It seems not to create properly an instance of the subclass. I think perhaps the analysis of dynamic dispatch is incomplete, then compiler fails initializing subclass correctly.
To prevent this issue, to specify `final` to the subclass declaration. It forces the compiler to call the initializer of the subclass.

```
final class AccountModel: Account { // add final keyword!
    [...]
    func foo(){
        println("bar")
    }
}
```